# React scroll component horizontally on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently building a card section which shows a horizontal list of cards. This list overflows, which makes the user have to scroll horizontally to view the offscreen cards.

To make this process easier for the user, I want to create buttons which scroll the horizontal list to the left or right.

I tried solving this by creating a reference to the horizontal list and apply a scrollX when I click on the previously mentioned button. This however, results in the following error:

```
Cannot add property scrollX, object is not extensible
```

My code:

```
const ref = useRef(null);

const scroll = () => {
  ref.scrollX += 20;
};

return (
  <div className={style.wrapper} id={id}>
    <Container className={style.container}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <button onClick={scroll}>TEST</button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
    <div className={style.projects} ref={ref}>
      {projects.map((data, index) => (
        <CardProject
          key={index}
          title={data.title}
          image={data.image}
          description={data.description}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In order to access a DOM Node with a Ref, you need to use `ref.current`; useRef is a container for a DOM node and you access that node with the `current` property.

Additionally, `scrollX` is a read-only property; you need to call `scrollLeft` to change the scroll position. For `scrollLeft` to work, you need to add an `overflow-x: scroll;` rule to the `style.projects` for it to work. (If `style.projects` is an object than change to `overflowX: 'scroll'`.)

To be able to scroll left or right, your can add a parameter to the function for the scroll offset, so it doesn't always scroll right:

```
const scroll = (scrollOffset) => {
  ref.current.scrollLeft += scrollOffset;
};
```

For this to work, you'll need two buttons in your JSX that pass in the offset values for left or right to the scroll function:

```
 <Row>
        <Col>
          <button onClick={() => scroll(-20)}>LEFT</button>
          <button onClick={() => scroll(20)}>RIGHT</button>
        </Col>
  </Row>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to make this scroll behaviour smooth?

Comment: @JonathanLauwers You can add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to the CSS for the `style.projects` but that isn't natively supported in Safari so you'd need some sort of polyfill like https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: Is this working? I tried it but not working as ittended